# Can this HTML be simplified by having jQuery create it?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code that creates a little speech bubble.  I am going to have a few dozen of them on an upcoming website, but the code to create the div's is a little too much for what I'd like to write out EVERY time I'd like to add a bubble.

What I'd like is to use jQuery, with the .html() attribute to create most of the code for me.  I am still learning jQuery so any help with this would be a great source of learning for me.

Here is current HTML:

```
<div id="bubbleWrapper">
    <div class="bubbleTop"></div>
    <div class="bubbleText">ryan jay</div>
</div>
```

I have a stylesheet for all of this, but it's not important right now.

What I'd like to be able to do, is when I want to add a bubble on the page, I'll just be able to use something like this:

```
<div class="bubble">ryan jay</div>
```

And the jQuery would recreate the first code example.  Is this something that is possible?  I am a bit lost on how I would do this.

Thank for your your time and help!

Comment: The jQuery methods you'd need would be `each`, `wrap` and `append`. See: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".bubble").each(function() {
    $wrapper = $("<div></div>").addClass("bubbleWrapper");
    $top = $("<div></div>").addClass("bubbleTop");
    $(this).addClass("bubbleText").wrap($wrapper).before($top);
});
```

Note I gave the wrapping `div` a class of `bubbleWrapper`, not an `id` as this will enable you to have multiple versions of this throughout your page without repeating the `id`, which would render the page invalid.

It's also worth noting that you would be completely cutting off this functionality from anyone who does not have javascript enabled. A better approach to DRY principles would be to create a function in your server-side code where you pass a string (to be used within the `bubbleText` div) and it generates this HTML for you.

Comment: This was super helpful.  I'm not too worried about it not working if a user doesn't have JS enabled, since it will only be used on a JS slideshow.  Thank you thank you!

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, please click the green tick on the left to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Oh don't worry, I will... You answered it too fast so I had to wait 6 minutes... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that will insert one of these bubble objects wherever you want:

```
function createBubble(text, insertPoint) {
    var elem = document.createElement("div");
    elem.className = "bubbleWrapper";
    elem.innerHTML = '<div class="bubbleTop"></div><div class="bubbleText">' + text + '</div>';
    insertPoint.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, insertPoint.nextSibling);
}
```

Note: I changed `bubbleWrapper` to a class name since you can't have the same ID on multiple objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you will create lots of elements, i suggest to use native javascript.

Because there is huge difference of time between jQuery and native javascript when creating dom elements. Maybe native javascript way is not cleaner, but it's definitely faster way.

Comment: +1 for sticking up for vanilla JS, but at least you know with jQuery its cross browser.